# Is it possible to save PSPDFDocumentEditor's document that uses custom data provider

Tags: ios, sdk, save, editor, pspdfkit

I am trying to us PDF editing feature of PSPDFViewController, but my application has a limitation that all data should be read/write on disk using secure file manger. So for this purpose I am using custom PSPDFDataProviding protocol implementation that handles read and writes. But when I  try to edit such document (e.g. add pages) using PSPDFDocumentEditorViewController, after pressing done I get saving dialog with only "Save as" option that leads to external storages.

If I create PSPDFDocument using on disk file URL it allows to save edited document in the same location, but doesn't allow me to control data read/write? Is there any way to store edited document using PSPDFDocument with custom data provider?

Comment: Our team replied to the same request in our support platform in the support ticket number: [#18615](https://pspdfkit.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/18615). In the future, for a faster response time, please reach out to our support portal at pspdfkit.com/support/request/ - we're happy to provide support there for our commercial SDK.